# ATG Web Commerce on JBoss versus Weblogic

Tags: java, performance, jboss, weblogic, atg

I'm working in an ATG Web Commerce environment and am evaluating JBoss as an app server versus Weblogic. Omitting the cost factor for a minute, do people have any experience on both platforms in terms of performance? Also, scalability is a very big factor and I'm interested in potentially using Coherence as a caching layer so that has me leaning towards Weblogic because I believe it's a pretty simple plugin.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS7 comes with Infinispan as default cache provider.

Here you find an overview about Infinispan:
http://www.jboss.org/infinispan

Answer (score 0):

ATG Repositories now directly support Coherence for caching in an app-server independent way.  All of the supported app-servers scale roughly the same.  Now that ATG is owned by Oracle, you will find that ATG will optimize on Weblogic as its primary platform, whereas it previously optimized on JBoss first.  You will be fine with either Weblogic or JBoss, unless you require some of the advanced managemenet capabilities of Weblogic.  ATG currently doesn't use any app-server specific features.  Also, ATG does not currently support JBoss AS7 or Infinispan.